# Configure clamdscan to scan all files on a system on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I did the following to install clamscan:

```
sudo aptitude install clamav 
sudo aptitude install clamav-daemon
```

and verified:

```
sudo ps -eal | grep clam
1 S 116 4788 1 2 80 0 - 4004 pause ? 00:00:13 freshclam
1 S 116 5930 1 0 80 0 - 69984 poll_s ? 00:00:00 clamd
```

however when I try to scan all the files on the the system by running

```
#sudo clamdscan /
```

I keep getting the following error message:

> lstat() failed: Permission denied. ERROR

However if I run

```
sudo clamscan /
```

it works, but this process is much longer and not a good option.

From my understanding clamd uses the user 'clamav' and is listed in the /etc/clamav/clamd.conf file. I've added the user clamav to the following groups : root, adm, sudo but it still doesn't work.

I've also tried disabling Apparmor as I read that could be the issue but no success.

Answer (score 23):

`sudo clamdscan /path/to/some_file.txt` will pass the request along to the clamd daemon. That daemun runs under a different user, which may not have access to `/path/to/some_file.txt`

However, the user invoking the command, may very well have access to that file. In order to pass your permissions along to the daemon, use the `--fdpass` flag:

```
--fdpass
    Pass the file descriptor permissions to clamd. This is useful if clamd is running as a different user as it is faster than streaming the file to clamd. Only available if connected to clamd via local(unix) socket.
```

In your case `sudo clamdscan --fdpass /` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

May be too late answer..., but I could not find any useful solution anywhere.

In cases of you can not use '--fdpass' with clamdscan or you use aother scan request method such as samba's vfs_virusfilter, check your linux securty system such as SELinux or AppArmor.

My workarould of the Ubuntu 20.04 host is add path to AppArmor config file.

/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.clamd

```
/path-to-allow-scan/** r,
```